# rails 3.2 : can not run in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, production-environment

There is a problem while running the application in production mode. I want to set as default to run it as production.

```
RAILS_ENV="production"
```

I added above line in application.rb but no luck.
Any idea how to make it possible. When I am uploading app to heroku it still runs in development, due to which I am not able to keep my databases separate.

Answer (score 1):

The application.rb is not the best place to define environment variables. On Heroku, you can define RAILS_ENV with heroku config:add RAILS_ENV=production

Answer (score 0):

Adding `RAILS_ENV="production"` to `application.rb` wont help. Read the [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3) on getting started.